# Call a template in another component with angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-template

I would like to call the template configuration.html in my **app.html**.

My architure looks like this with ionic :

```html
>src
  >app 
     - app.component.ts
     - app.html
     - app.module.ts
  >pages
    > menus
       - configuration.html
       - menus.component.ts
```

**configuration.html** (I want to call this html in app.html):
*Note* : if I put this code directly in app.html, I can build correctly my app and it works.

```html
<ion-menu persistent="true" [content]="content" side="left" id="menuParameter">
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="default">
            <ion-title>Configuration</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>

        <ion-list>


            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Mode1</ion-label>
                <ion-toggle color="energized"></ion-toggle>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Mode2</ion-label>
                <ion-toggle color="danger" [(ngModel)]="isToggled" (ionChange)="notify()"></ion-toggle>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-menu persistent="true" [content]="content" side="right" id="menuInformation">
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="default">
            <ion-title>Menu2</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

**menus.component.ts** :

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Logger } from '../../app/logger.service'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NavController, NavParams, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';



@Component({
  selector: 'configuration-component',
  templateUrl: 'configuration.html'
})

/**
 * Contain link with 
 */
export class MenusPage {
    constructor(){}
}
```

**app.html** :

```html
<configuration-component></configuration-component>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Finally **app.component.ts** i use this :

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { MenusPage } from '../pages/menus/menus.component';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';




@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  rootPage:any = HomePage;
  


  constructor(public events: Events,platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {

      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
      this.isToggled = false;
    });
  }
  



}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenusPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(AppComponent)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    AppComponent,
    MenusPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Geolocation,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[image]

any help please ?

[image]

Comment: Hi, you make it work ? Could you post here the correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `selector`  to `MenusPage`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'configuration-component',
  templateUrl: 'configuration.html'
})
export class MenusPage { ... }
```

Use it to include it in the app component HMTL

```
<configuration-component> </configuration-component>
```

**Points to Remember**

- These component should be declared under declarations of the respective module
- If they are from multiple modules, ensure that component is exported from its parent module
- Selectors should be unique across the application.

Comment: I've got an error <ion-nav #content></ion-nav>
menu.js:324Menu: must have a [content] element to listen for drag events on.

Comment: can you elaborate ? when you are getting this error, and in which component?

Comment: I've got this error in the vendor.js (generated during build process) and there is no more indications. Are you sure it is possible to call a html template in app.html ? in fact if I don't use a template, so I write all my code in app.html it works, but I would like to organize my code in a better way

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: no but I will update my code below, I hope it could help.

Comment: Ok. @Alex99 that would help

Comment: @Aravind you fix that ? Could you to us ??

Comment: @DanielArantesLoverde I m sorry what was your question.

Comment: @Aravind you fix that error? Could you show to us? Post your answer here?

Comment: @DanielArantesLoverde The question was changed for various versions.

Comment: Strange, i did everything you post here, still getting the same error. Could you help with that?